# Matrix indexing with matrices in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to pull values from a matrix that is serving essentially as a look up table. To do this I have a matrix of row coordinates and a matrix of column coordinates. Is there a way that I can pull the values as follows:

```
A(R, C)
```

or

```
A(R(:), C(:))
```

For example:

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4; 
      5, 6, 7, 8; 
      9, 0, 1, 2; 
      3, 4, 5, 6 ];

R = [ 1, 2; 
      1 2];
C = [ 1, 1; 
      1 1];
```

I would like to find some command so that

```
A(R, C) =

1, 5
1, 5
```

or

```
A(R(:), C(:)) =

1
1
5
5
```

What actually happens when you do these commands is you get every permutation of the matrix. So in my example, you get a resultant 4x4 matrix consisting of

```
A(1,1)  A(1,1)  A(1,1)  A(1,1)
A(1,1)  A(1,1)  A(1,1)  A(1,1)
A(2,1)  A(2,1)  A(2,1)  A(2,1)
A(2,1)  A(2,1)  A(2,1)  A(2,1)
```

Is there a way to just do the indexing pair-wise down each index matrix/vector so the result shows

```
A(1,1)  A(2,1)
A(1,1)  A(2,1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you are pointing to a delicate issue with Matlab indexing.
To solve this issue, you need to convert the row-col indices `R`, `C` to [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). One simple way to do so is using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
 A( sub2ind( size(A), R, C ) );
```

Here's how it works

```
>> A(sub2ind(size(A),R,C))
ans =
 1     5
 1     5

>> A(sub2ind(size(A),R(:),C(:)))
ans =
 1
 1
 5
 5
```

---

If you are tight on runtime and want to avoid the overhead of `sub2ind` you can convert the indices directly yourself:

```
 A( size(A,1)*(C-1)+R )
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation too. Both of those one-liners work well. Can you explain how the direct index conversion works a little more in your answer? It's not intuitive to me

Comment: please see all about linear indexing [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). @marcman

Comment: Ah gotcha. That makes sense--it's essentially a matrix version of the standard `(j-1) * d1 + i` offsetting. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
>> arrayfun(@(x,y) A(x,y), R, C)
ans =
     1     5
     1     5
```

You get the result in the same size as `R` and `C` not as a vector.

Comment: with `sub2ind` and the direct method I proposed you get the result in exactly the same shape as `R` and `C` - `arrayfun` does not provide any advantage with that respect.

Comment: @Shai, I didn't mean as an advantage over your solution but I removed the word advantage anyway.